# how to select options for the R scripts that will execute in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making a R shiny app, and I've already got two separate R scripts (Domain1.R and Domain2.R) that I'm putting into R shiny.

These R scripts extract tables from PDF files (it tested and works well). I've added options for listing the domains "Domain1" and "Domain2," as well as an Extract Button. The problem is that after selecting the options and clicking the extract button, Both R scripts are executed. When the relevant option is chosen, I want either one R script to run.

The domain selection(choices: domain 1 and domain 2 should call the corresponding R scripts, It should run the code "Domain1" if I pick domain1 from the choices, however, it now performs both the "Domain1" and "Domain2" R scripts. How can this problem be resolved?

I'm new to the R shiny, and I'd appreciate it if anyone could assist me.

Sharing the entire code below:

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      theme = "spacelab",
      "Dataset",
      tabPanel("Study report extracting",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file1", "Select datasets:",
                           accept = c(
                             "text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")
                 ),
                 tags$hr(),
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 textInput("txt", "Study info:", "Study name read"),
                 sliderInput("slider", "Tables to read:", 1, 100, 30),
                 tags$h5("Prepare extraction"),
                 actionButton("dataset", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("contents"),
                 tabsetPanel(
                   
                   tabPanel("PDF File select",
                            h4("Domains"),
                            tableOutput("table"),
                            h3("Extracting..."),
                            selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a PDF", choices = c('Domain1')),
                            tableOutput("preview"),
                            actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary"),
                            selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a PDF", choices = c('Domain2')),
                            tableOutput("preview"),
                            actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
                            
                            
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Raw data", "TBD"),
                   tabPanel("calculation", "TBD")
                 )
               )
      ), # end of first tabpanel
      tabPanel("Calculation",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file2", "Select datasets:",
                           accept = c(
                             "text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")
                 ),
                 tags$hr(),
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 textInput("txt2", "Study info:", "Study name read"),
                 sliderInput("slider", "Tables to read:", 1, 100, 30),
                 tags$h5("Preparing the calculation"),
                 actionButton("dataset2", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("contents2"),
                 
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Datasets",
                            h4("Domains"),
                            tableOutput("table2"),
                            h3("Calculating...")
                   )
                 )
               )
      ),
      tabPanel("Comparision",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file3", "Select study report and datasets:"),
                 textInput("txt3", "Study info:", "Study name read"),
                 tags$h5("Prepare comparison"),
                 actionButton("action2", "Compare", class = "btn-primary")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("PDF File select",
                            h4("Domains"),
                            tableOutput("table3"),
                            h3("Comparing..."),
                   ),
                   tabPanel("calculation data", "TBD")
                 )
               )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$contents <- renderTable({
      # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
      # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
      # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
      # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
      # be found.
      inFile <- input$file1
      
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
      
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
    output$contents2 <- renderTable({
      # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
      # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
      # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
      # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
      # be found.
      inFile <- input$file2
      
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
      
      read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
    output$txtout <- renderText({
      paste(input$txt, input$slider, format(input$date), sep = ", ")
    })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df <- c("Domain1","Domain2","Domain3","Domain4")
    })
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
      df <- c("Domain1","Domain2","Domain3","Domain4")
    })
    output$table3 <- renderTable({
      df <- c("Domain1","Domain2","Domain3","Domain4")
    })
    observeEvent(input$dataset, {
      source("Domain1.R", local = TRUE)
    })
    observeEvent(input$dataset2, {
      source("calculation.R", local = TRUE)
    })
    observeEvent(input$pdfExtract1, {     #When I press the extract button, nothing happens.
      source("Domain1.R", local = TRUE)
    })
    observeEvent(input$pdfExtract1, {    #When I press the extract button, nothing happens.
      source("Domain2.R", local = TRUE)
    })
    
    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some elements sharing the same id here:

```
                    selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a PDF", choices = c('Domain1')),
                    tableOutput("preview"),
                    actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary"),
                    selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a PDF", choices = c('Domain2')),
                    tableOutput("preview"),
                    actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
```

This is wrong. Replace this code block with:

```
                    selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a PDF", choices = c("Domain1", "Domain2")),
                    tableOutput("preview"),
                    actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
```

Then observe the click on the button, and run the script corresponding to the selection:

```
observeEvent(input$pdfExtract, {    
  if(input$pdfExtract1 == "Domain1"){ 
    source("Domain1.R", local = TRUE)
  }else{
    source("Domain2.R", local = TRUE)
  }
})
```

But there's something not clear in your app: it also runs `Domain1.R` when the user clicks on the `dataset` button:

```
observeEvent(input$dataset, {
  source("Domain1.R", local = TRUE)
})
```

I don't know what you want to do so I cannot further comment this point.

Comment: Yes, you're right; I should get rid of the duplicate code. The loops also work nicely for me.